# Can you initiate maneuvers with weapons other than those the discipline favors?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

When playing a class from Tome of Battle: Book of Nine Swords can you initiate manuevers while not weilding a disciplines favored weapon? For example: could one use Desert Wind manuevers without weilding a scimitar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

Favored weapons are relevant for certain feats, but they are never a requirement to initiate a maneuver. Any requirements for initiating a maneuver, other than knowing it and having it available (rather than expended) will be explicitly listed in the maneuver's entry in ToB; if you don't see a required weapon, there isn't one.